# Whitelist tokens for text generation (XLNet, GPT-2) in huggingface-transformers

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

In the documentation on text generation (https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#generative-models) there is the option to put

```
bad_words_ids (List[int], optional) – List of token ids that are not allowed to be generated. In order to get the tokens of the words that should not appear in the generated text, use tokenizer.encode(bad_word, add_prefix_space=True).
```

Is there also the option to put something along the lines of "allowed_words_ids"? The idea would be to restrict the language of the generated texts.

Comment: why not to use the "bad_word" for all the word that are not in your whilelist?

Comment: we would have to include practically almost the vocabulary, but we will try, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also suggest to do what Sahar Mills said. You can do it in the following way.

1. You get the whole vocab of the model you are using, e.g.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Load tokenizer
checkpoint = "CenIA/distillbert-base-spanish-uncased" #Example model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

vocab = tokenizer.get_vocab()
list(vocab.keys())[:100] # to see the first 100 words
```

2. Define words you do want in the model.

```
words_to_delete = ['forzado', 'vendieron', 'verticales'] # or load them from somewhere else
```

3. Define function to create the bad_words_ids, that is, the whole model vocab minus the words you want in the model

```
def create_bad_words_ids(bad_words_ids, words_to_delete):
  for pictogram in range(len(words_to_delete)):
    if words_to_delete[pictogram] in bad_words_ids:
      bad_words_ids.remove(words_to_delete[pictogram])
  return bad_words_ids

bad_words_ids = create_bad_words_ids(bad_words_ids=bad_words_ids, words_to_delete=words_to_delete)
print(bad_words_ids)
```

Hope it helps,
cheers